# How to disable the letter tail from the last letter of a word in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I have this font that is adding some special curves to the last letter of a word. Is there any way of removing this?

Font name: Rolling Pen

[image]

In the above image you can see the letter "e" having two variants.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Christian Flores helped me find this CSS setting:

```
-moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" 0, "calt" 0;
-ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" 0, "calt" 0;
-o-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" 0, "calt" 0;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" 0, "calt" 0;
font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" 0, "calt" 0;
```

It's all I was looking for!

Comment: Unless you provide a [mcve] of your problem, there's little chance that anyone will help you.

Comment: @DanMiller - if you could reproduce the problem using a jsFiddle - that's extremely helpful. The average person seeing this image is going to know nothing about this particular font, nor have the ability to mess around with it to see what can be done. It helps if you give some code to work with. This is a coding Q + A site. ---- Moving on, the styling of the characters, as you're probably aware, is a product of whatever font you're using. I don't know a ton about fonts + css, but I think you're stuck here unless you use a different font. Maybe contact the font creator.

Comment: thank you for the advice mmcrae, I'll see if I can find another version of this font.

Comment: There was never a `-ms-` prefix for the `font-feature-settings` property, IE has supported it unprefixed since v10. The only major browsers that currently require that property to be prefixed are Android Chrome, Blackberry & UC Browser so, depending on how far back you need to go with your browser support, you could probably remove the other prefixed versions too. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all of the font-weights included. You could change it to "Basic One", "Basic Two" or "Curly".

Example here:
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/rolling-pen/webfont_preview.html

Comment: thank you my friend, your link inspired me to find the solution!